# How would I resolve "Error adding test case [12345] to test run: File does not exist. Could not find file..."?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, microsoft-test-manager

I am using TFS Build with template `LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml` and attempting to run some tests in our test environment. In Microsoft Test Manager I have setup an environment, test plan and test case. During the test run portion of the build I receive the following in the test run log:

> Error adding test case [1234] to test run: File does not exists. Could
>   not find file \MyServer\Stage\Build123\My.Test.Assembly.dll

The path given in the error message is the correct path to the staging directory. The assembly is the correct test assembly that is the associated automation to the test case.

**Important fact:** We don't copy our assemblies directly in our stage directory. Instead we stage a package (a zip file basically) of all the assemblies.

It appears that the test run is *expecting* the assembly to be in the root of the staging directory.

***Here are my questions:***

Can I specify the test run to look in a different location for the test assembly?

*Or* Do I have to have the test assemblies in the root stage folder?

Comment: How do you deploy your **application under test** to the test environment? Are you using _Deployment_ part of the `LabDefaultTemplate11.xaml`. If yes, are you using `$(BuildLocation)` variable as argument when calling your deployment scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to change the directory. I figured it out via [this msdn forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e31b70a0-5817-41dd-80b3-80eae1880d11/builddeploytest-editing-test-dlls-location-the-test-agent-uses?forum=tfsgeneral).

Basically, I had to edit the `LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml` build template.

1. Find the Running Tests activity under Run Tests on Environment -> Run Tests -> Running Tests
2. Look for `TestDirectory` under Properties
3. Change it to the folder you need (it defaults to BuildLocation)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your test assembly to the deployment section in your automated test settings.
Open your automated test setting, goto Advanced > Deployment; add your assembly file to the test setting.